# Update/Modify a single value in database only in VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

Lets say some of my hotel room status in my database (Ms-Access) are "Available"(Where the room type is what I selected). I need to modify only one status from "Available" to "Check In". But when I modify, all of the status will change from "Available" to "Check In".

```
Dim sql3 As String
sql3 = " UPDATE [Room] SET [Status] = '" & "Check-In" & "' Where RoomType = '" & ComboBox1.Text.ToString & "'"
Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql3, conn)
Try
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd3.Dispose()
    MsgBox("Successful")

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need a where clause more exclusive than the RoomType - Riim Number perhaps?  I like that you broke the SQL string to concat a string.

Comment: On another note look into disposing your objects... and using params...

Comment: I find when writing SQL to try to think like your assistant. SQL is pretty English like... So if your boss Said.. Update Room Set Status  blah blah blah".. Me thinks you would ask him either "Which room?" or "WHAT??? ALL OF THEM????"

Comment: @Trevor no, the `WHERE` clause with multiple criteria would be `WHERE A = 1 AND B = 2 AND RoomStyle = 'Storage_Closet'`

Comment: @djv oops... ha ha ... I thought it looked wrong... thanks